# How to create a data frame that shows the NULL & Isnan values in the rows?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I want to count the Null/Isnan values that each dataframe contains while looping over a list of dataframes in pyspark.

This is the code that I already have written.

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import plotly.express as px
import pyspark.pandas as ps


data = [
    (None,"CA",np.NaN,"2021-07-24 12:01:19.000"), ("Julia","",None, None),
    ("Ram",None,200.0, ""), ("Ramya","NULL",np.NAN, "2021-07-24 12:01:19.000")
]
df =spark.createDataFrame(data,["name","state","number", "timestamp"])

data = [
    (None,"CA",np.NaN,"2021-07-24 12:01:19.000"), ("Julia","",None, None),
    ("Ram",None,200.0, ""), ("Ramya","NULL",np.NAN, "2021-07-24 12:01:19.000")
]
df2 =spark.createDataFrame(data,["name","state","number", "timestamp"])

list_of_df = [df, df2]

list_disp_df = []
for df in list_of_df:

    disp_df = df.select(*[
        (
            F.count(F.when((F.isnan(c) | \
            F.col(c).contains('None') | \
           (F.col(c) == '' ) | \
            F.col(c).isNull()), c)) if t not in ("timestamp", "date")
            else F.count(F.when(F.col(c).isNull() | F.col(c).contains('None') |  (F.col(c) == '' )  , c))
        ).alias(c)
        for c, t in df.dtypes if c in df.columns
    ])
    # File date / issue / count 
    #display(disp_df)
    list_disp_df.append(disp_df)

4
for dis in list_disp_df:
  display(dis)
```

---

My expected output is like following for every dataframe I loop over:

```
--------------------
|Count_type| Count |
|-------------------
| Isnan    | 5     |
| Null     | 7     |
--------------------
```

Hope you have a solution.

Thank you.

|

Comment: When does a value count as `Isnan` and when as `Null`, especially for non-number data types?

Comment: @werner, i am maybe causing confusing with my expected output.
The numbers are fictional, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def union_all(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.union, dfs)

col_level_stats = [
        df.select(
            *[
                F.count(F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), 1)).alias(f"isNull"),
                F.count(F.when(F.col(c).contains("None"), 1)).alias(f"None_"),
                F.count(F.when(F.col(c) == "", 1)).alias(f"emptyStr")
            ]
        )
        for c, t in df.dtypes
        if c in df.columns
]

combined_stats = union_all(*col_level_stats)
aggregated_stats = combined_stats.groupBy().agg(*(F.sum(c).alias(c) for c in combined_stats.columns))
pivoted_stats = aggregated_stats.toPandas().transpose()
pivoted_stats
```

Here's a solution that might work, the high level steps are:

1. counting each column for their respective conditions (isNull, empty string, etc)
2. Store each column into a list of dataframes based on step 1
3. Union all the df and aggregate each column and then transpose it (via Pandas dataframe)
4. You can convert it back to spark dataframe if you need to

Do note that pyspark treats None, Null and empty strings differently so your results may look funny, you may need to refine your conditions for each null record.